# Select2 not applying on dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a function to create dynamic div via template literal, inside each div i want to add a select2 select filter, but when the dynamic div is rendered in my page, select2 isn't initialize, anyone know how to fix this? below is a example snippet code:

javascript :

```
function render_report_grid(data){
            var details = `<select class="filter_select2 pull-right" 
                           id="filter_select2_${data.id}" multiple="multiple" name="select_project">
                           </select>`
}

$('.filter_select2').select2({placeholder: "Select parent",});
```

Comment: can you add a snippet or a JSFiddle for this?

Comment: you will need to re-execulte select2 on each content generated dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You should add the initiation part inside the function like :

```
function render_report_grid(data){
    var details = `<select class="filter_select2 pull-right" 
                  id="filter_select2_${data.id}" multiple="multiple" name="select_project">
                  </select>`

    $('.filter_select2').select2("destroy").select2({placeholder: "Select parent"});
}
```

So every time you're adding a new select tag you'll init it to be a select2 instance.

Comment: hi @Zakaria, unfortunately this doesnt work, in fact i can only render 1 dynamic div after adding the code

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are creating the select2 before you have added it to your page, so when you are doing:

```
$('.filter_select2').select2({placeholder: "Select parent"});
```

The jquery selector has not found anything, so you need to add it before to the html:

```
var details = '<select class="filter_select2 pull-right" id="filter_select2_${data.id}" multiple="multiple"name="select_project"></select>';
$('some_jquery_selector').append(details);
$('.filter_select2').select2({placeholder: "Select parent"});
```